# Is there method similar to extend but for rows (creating a new row)?

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have the following datatable:

```
let DataSource = datatable(Name:string, value1:real, value2:real)
[
    'Section 1', 2211.47, 3564.05,
    'Transfer 1', 3075.44, 3717.51,
    'Transfer 2', 3460.66, 4194.16,
    'Transfer 3', 4819.36, 482.02,
    'Section 2', 1742.02, 11971.05
];
```

I need to add to this datatable a new row which with the following values:

Name: Transfer
value1: sum of value1 for all Names containing Transfer
value2: average of value2 for all Names containing Transfer

The expected outcome is:

```
let DataSource = datatable(Name:string, value1:real, value2:real)
[
    'Section 1', 2211.47, 3564.05,
    'Transfer', 11355.46, 2797.9,
    'Section 2', 1742.02, 11971.05
];
```

I don't know if there is a method similar to extend which can create a new row to achieve this result. I tried this way:

```
let DataSource = datatable(Name:string, value1:real, value2:real)
[
    'Section 1', 2211.47, 3564.05,
    'Transfer 1', 3075.44, 3717.51,
    'Transfer 2', 3460.66, 4194.16,
    'Transfer 3', 4819.36, 482.02,
    'Section 2', 1742.02, 11971.05
];
DataSource
| as t1 
| union (t1 | summarize Name = "Transfer", value1 = sum(value1), value2 = sum(value2))
| where Name !in ("Transfer 1", "Transfer 2", "Transfer 3")
```

It works but I think it will take a lot of cpu memory if we are working in huge dataset.

Is there a better approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `extend` operator to modify the `Name` column to group all the names containing `Transfer` and then use the `summarize` operator to compute the sum of `value1` and the average of `value2` for each unique value of `Name`. Below is the code:

**Code:**

```
let DataSource = datatable(Name:string, value1:real, value2:real)
[
'Section 1', 2211.47, 3564.05,
'Transfer 1', 3075.44, 3717.51,
'Transfer 2', 3460.66, 4194.16,
'Transfer 3', 4819.36, 482.02,
'Section 2', 1742.02, 11971.05
];
DataSource
| extend Name=iif(Name contains "Transfer", "Transfer", Name)
| summarize value1=sum(value1), value2=avg(value2) by Name
```

This code  uses the  `extend`  operator to modify the  `Name`  column using the  `iif`  function. The  `iif`  function checks if the  `Name`  column contains the word "**Transfer**", then replaces the value of the  `Name`  column with the string "Transfer". Otherwise, it leaves the value of the  `Name`  column unchanged. The  `summarize`  operator is then used to compute the sum of  `value1`  and the average of  `value2`  for each unique value of  `Name`.

**Output**:

| Name | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Section 1 | 2211.47 | 3564.05 |
| Transfer | 11355.46 | 2797.896666666667 |
| Section 2 | 1742.02 | 11971.05 |

[demo](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12QMW/CMBCF9/yKEwtEsqyc49iEKlvnLnSrOphwIEuJIzkOait+PHYCqsDTe+fv7HvXUYB3E8x+mHxL0MAxmmAOHW0+TE+7MXjrzgwuppsId55MdzdiNnn2lUE86z21wQ4OcM1ACEQuNYOyUpIXFVuQT2/ceCI/M2WhKy5lFBo1r/CVEYmRquBKMZBYS47qlSkjI7dY8zIxW8ELwZ6nSa+glvMNINYa4zjZ91v2nzm7Av0EckdIgRtrT3NyaAcXjHUjrB7/rdiTTlQeu8ep7423f3RfUhMLm0Xmj1015nJeaiKHw+/cewNK2HNNewEAAA==)

Comment: Works perfectly ! thanks :)